# SQL Error multi-part identifier

Tags: sql

CAn someone help me fix this SQL statement? I am trying to retrieve story, creation date from the story table and the company role from the member table, but am getting an error:

The multi-part identifier "s.ProjectIterationMemberID" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "s.StoryID" could not be bound.

```
SELECT s.Story, s.CreationDate, m.CompanyRole FROM Story s, Member m INNER JOIN    
ProjectIterationMember pim On m.MemberID = pim.MemberID AND 
pim.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID INNER JOIN 
ProjectStoryFactors psf On s.StoryID = psf.StoryID JOIN AgileFactors af ON 
psf.AgileFactorID = af.AgileFactorID WHERE StoryCategoryID = 1 AND af.Name = '" + tag + "'"
```

my table structure is as follows:

> Member {MemberID (PK), CompanyRole}
>
> ProjectIterationMember
>   {ProjectIterationMemberID (PK),
>   MemberID (FK)}
>
> Story {StoryID (PK),
>   ProjectIterationMemberID,
>   StoryCategoryID, Story, CreationDate}
>
> ProjectStoryFactors
>   {ProjectStoryFactorID (PK), StoryID,
>   AgileFactorID}
>
> AgileFactors {AgileFactorID (PK),
>   Name}

Comment: Please, in the future, don't write your SQL statements as if they were sentences. Use new lines for your joins, where clause, etc. It will make it *much* more readable than what's here. See @JonH's answer for an example of good formatting. While I prefer keeping the `ON` and the join condition on the same line as the join specification, his is much more readable.

Comment: There is also an extra double quote at the end of your WHERE clause

Comment: @theChrisKent - it's a snippet from a string concat query in some IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   s.Story, 
   s.CreationDate,
   m.CompanyRole
FROM
   Story s
INNER JOIN ProjectiterationMember pm 
ON
   pm.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID
INNER JOIN Member m
ON
   m.MemberID = pm.MemberID
INNER JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf 
ON 
   psf.StoryID = s.StoryID
INNER JOIN AgileFactors af
ON  
   af.AgileFactorID=psf.AgileFactorID
WHERE
   s.StoreCategoryID = 1 AND af.Name  = '" + tag + "'"
```

Comment: How does this get +2 with 2 tables gone missing?

Comment: You left out the entire WHERE clause and several other items.

Comment: @JonH I thought it better to explain `why` it didn't work and a working query would help an obvious beginner who's asked similar questions on SO already.

Comment: @cyberkiwi - The point I showed him was that the comma was not correct, he can continue the code.  That is how we learn keep coding.  In any case I edited to add additional joins.

Comment: JonH - fyi I didn't take part in downvoting your answer (not even the original) but do as you please.

Comment: @cyberkiwi - That's fine but I don't really take the points to mean much, besides I can't trade them in for a stack overflow tshirt.

Answer (score 2):

You broke the ANSI join chain with a comma between story and member

```
SELECT s.Story, s.CreationDate, m.CompanyRole
FROM Story s
INNER JOIN ProjectIterationMember pim
 On pim.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID
INNER JOIN Member m
 ON m.MemberID = pim.MemberID
INNER JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf
 On s.StoryID = psf.StoryID
JOIN AgileFactors af
 ON psf.AgileFactorID = af.AgileFactorID
WHERE StoryCategoryID = 1 AND af.Name = '" + tag + "'"
```

This is your query broken into blocks.  Mixing ANSI and non-ANSI in the FROM clause makes things tricky.

---

SELECT s.Story, s.CreationDate, m.CompanyRole FROM

**Story s**

,  -- the little comma

Member m INNER JOIN
ProjectIterationMember pim On m.MemberID = pim.MemberID AND 
pim.ProjectIterationMemberID = **s.ProjectIterationMemberID** INNER JOIN 
ProjectStoryFactors psf On **s.StoryID** = psf.StoryID JOIN AgileFactors af ON 
psf.AgileFactorID = af.AgileFactorID

WHERE StoryCategoryID = 1 AND af.Name = '" + tag + "'"

---

The alias "s" is defined in the first comma portion, it cannot be "seen" from the 2nd part.

Comment: +1 For the nice explanation and, you know, including everything from the original query :)

Comment: @theChrisKent Nasty people who didn't like my comments on the other answer, which wouldn't have been accepted if it wasn't prompted and updated to a cut-and-paste solution.

Comment: I didn't know points meant that much.  My point here is to give answers and move on..no drama sir!